# How do I update a module schema?

Tags: updating

I have already created a module (test_auth), which I installed on a Drupal site.

I added `test_auth_schema()` & `test_auth_update_8101()` to test_auth.install. When I run `drupal cache:rebuild`, it doesn't create my table in the database.

I put `echo 1; exit;` in both functions, but they don't seem invoked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Run the update.php script.

Comment: Hi @Kstack via URL? project url/update.php ?

Comment: yes. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x

Comment: Use drush updb or run update.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply clearing the cache doesn't make Drupal do anything on updated modules. `hook_update_N()` implementations are invoked from [update.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/update.php/8.4.x), similarly to what happens with previous Drupal versions. This means, for example, that once Drupal runs `mymodule_update_8001()`, it will not run the same update hook again; for new updates, `mymodule_update_8002()` is required.

Differently from `hook_update_N()`, `hook_schema()` is not invoked when a module is updated, but when a module is installed. So, it is expected that `test_auth_schema()` is not invoked, when the module is not installed.

The alternative to run update.php is using Drush (i.e. `drush updatedb`).